# How to acquire the object ID?

Tags: javascript, objectid

I want to dynamically create images to a screen, but later when I touch them, I would like to get the object ID which I touch, in order to delete or manipulate it.

I am posting the code which I am dynamically creating the images. Any help on how to acquire the images(object) ID?

```
this.i = this.i + 1;

this.icon[this.i] = this.add.sprite(this.cnodeoding, 100, "image");
```

Comment: please describe your html part how you are trying to implement this code.

Comment: Hi , I am using phaser.io as the html page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an element in HTML e.g. `<image id="i">` and a correspond variable in JS e.g. `var image = document.querySelector('image')`, you can get the id easily: `var id = image.id`.

Comment: Hi , thanks for the reply. Is there any event which I will catch and use it to grap the ID of the object created before?

Comment: @PetePan Yes, there are a lot of events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events Maybe 'click' or 'touchstart' will be useful in your case.